# Creating iterators with counting intersection

Tags: python

I need to read a text file, calculate a specific score, and then write a new file.

```
f=open("test.txt")
fw=open("test_result.txt","w")
```

This file, "f", contains three delimited contents like this:

```
'Washington\t\5\tWaterpark,Themepark,Playground,Spaceneedle,Carousel\n'
'California\t\6\tWaterpark,Themepark,Disneyland,Legoland,Carousel,Sixflag\n'
'Arizona\t\3\tWaterpark,Playground,Themepark\n'
```

I want to find the number of items that are found only in the intersection for each combination of lists in the third column of each line.

```
len(intersect_WAandCA) #3: 'Waterpark, Themepark, Carousel':intersection between 5 lists in first line and 6 lists in second line
len(intersect_WAandAZ) #3: 'Waterpark, Themepark, Playground'
len(intersect_CAandAZ) #2: 'Waterpakr, Playground'
```

From this, I want to make a new file as follows.

```
5 Washington 6 California 3
5 Washington 3 Arizona 3
6 California 3 Arizona 2
```

I've tried to figure out the way with "from itertools import combinations" like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553728/counting-intersections-for-all-combinations-in-a-list-of-sets). To be honest, I am new to Python. I couldn't find the way to create iterators with a loop and make a new file. Actually, the file that I have contains more than 100 rows.

What should I do for creating (n *n-1)/2 all combinations?

Comment: Are you sure there are backslashes before the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input file is a tab-delimited file, I'd use the `csv` module to read the data; use `set()` to then creates sets of the 3rd column:

```
import csv

with open('test.txt', 'rb') as infh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh, delimiter='\t')
    data = [(row[0], set(row[2].split(','))) for row in reader]
```

Now we have data we can work with; we can ignore the second column, that same number is the length of our sets.

```
from itertools import combinations

with open('test2.txt', 'wb') as outfh:
    writer = csv.writer(outfh, delimiter='\t')
    for (state1, features1), (state2, features2) in combinations(data, 2):
        overlap = len(features1 & features2)
        writer.writerow([
            len(features1), state1, 
            len(features2), state2,
            overlap])
```

This produces:

```
>>> import csv
>>> data = '''\
... Washington\t5\tWaterpark,Themepark,Playground,Spaceneedle,Carousel
... California\t6\tWaterpark,Themepark,Disneyland,Legoland,Carousel,Sixflag
... Arizona\t3\tWaterpark,Playground,Themepark
... '''.splitlines(True)
>>> reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')
>>> data = [(row[0], set(row[2].split(','))) for row in reader]
>>> import sys
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter='\t')
>>> for (state1, features1), (state2, features2) in combinations(data, 2):
...     overlap = len(features1 & features2)
...     writer.writerow([
...         len(features1), state1,
...         len(features2), state2,
...         overlap])
... 
5   Washington  6   California  3
5   Washington  3   Arizona 3
6   California  3   Arizona 2
```

Comment: So perfect! You are genius! Perfectly working and So cool! How well-written the code is!!!